# JMS messageSelector (WebSphere)

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, ejb, ejb-3.0

I've created a MDB that consumes messages from a TIBCO EMS Queue. This is working fine, consuming all messages. Now I need to implement a message selector to consume only messages of one specific type.

The problem is that my messageSelector is not working and MDB is still consuming all messages.

My MDB

```
@MessageDriven(
       name = "MDBPscInformationResponseReceiver", 
       activationConfig = {
          @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
          @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName = "destination", propertyValue ="jms/PscInformationResponseQueue"),
          @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName = "messageSelector", propertyValue ="TipoMensagem='UPDATE'")
       }
    )
public class MDBPscInformationResponseReceiver implements MessageListener {
```

Message received (header)

```
TextMessage={ Header={ 
    JMSMessageID={ID:EMS-SERVER.BD0DC51386DFD35EC0:18012} 
    JMSDestination={Queue[WAI.SDAGL.08502.PSC.RPL]} 
    JMSReplyTo={null} JMSDeliveryMode={NON_PERSISTENT} 
    JMSRedelivered={false} 
    JMSCorrelationID={} 
    JMSType={}
    JMSTimestamp={Wed Jun 05 11:08:07 BST 2013} 
    JMSExpiration={0} 
    JMSPriority={4}
} 
Properties={ 
    TipoMensagem={String:CONSULTA} 
} 
Text={<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I'm sending the message using GEMS (I've a printscreen but I can't post images yet)

```
JMSDeliveryMode     NON_PERSISTENT
JMSDestination      WAI.SDAGL.08502.PSC.RPL
JMSCorrelationID
JMSType
JMSExpiration       0
JMSPriority         4
TipoMensagem        CONSULTA
```

I've already read the documentation from java (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncgw.html) and out of ideas.

Comment: Does not look incorrect... Maybe the problem is unrelated - stale code deployed, a broken Websphere profile?